# Removing .html from a link using NGINX

Tags: html, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I've this configuration for my nginx site-available file. It creates a link like https://website.com/news-id.html

What i want to do is to remove "news-" and .html from the link and make the url clean with just https://website.com/id

I have tried several methods but everytime i run into a redirection loop.

**I tried several times to put the code here but failed. So here is the link to the config file https://jpst.it/1AKIf

Comment: `I have tried several methods` share those with us

Answer (score 1):

Try this config.

```
server {
    location / {

        # Redirects to the version without .html
        if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 302 /$1;  }

        # Tries the uri, .html file and the news prefix.
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html news-$uri news-$uri/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It took around 3 hours to find it.